# Aboard/On board difference

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, difference, word-difference

Do "They came aboard the ship" and "They came on board the ship" have any difference in meaning?

Are **aboard** and **on board** interchangeble?

- They were aboard the vessel.
- They were on board the vessel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/onboard-on-board/):

> on board usually means the same as aboard, and aboard would usually work in its place. Aboard would not make sense as a replacement for onboard.

This said, **on board** is the same as **aboard**, but not the same as **onboard**.

Comment: so a bit like 'all dogs are animals but animals are not all dogs'?

Comment: I would add that "on board" is often used in a figurative sense that (to me) wouldn't sound right with "aboard". For example, after a discussion of a plan, you might be asked "are you on board?", meaning something like "are you with us in being willing to go along with this plan?". "Are you aboard?" wouldn't sound right to me at all in this context.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I think it's comparing "on board" as in the noun phrase; the state of being on a vehicle, and "onboard" the adjective. So you would say "onboard staff" but not "aboard staff"; but you could equally say "I'm on board the HMS Victory" and "I'm aboard the HMS victory".

Comment: Please explain also the difference between on board and aboard in your answer.

Comment: Both these words are adverbs of place.

Answer (score 1):

"They were aboard the vessel" simply states that they were present or inside the vessel without specifying their exact location within it. It implies that they were on the vessel but does not necessarily focus on their specific position. On the other hand, "They were on board the vessel" emphasizes their presence and location specifically on the vessel. It highlights that they were not only present but also situated inside the vessel, suggesting a stronger connection to it.

Look at this example, it may help you:

> This summer, 41 UBC alumni and friends participated in expeditions to the Canadian Arctic and the legendary Northwest Passage. Presentations, conversations and learning accompanied their exploration of the great outdoors **aboard** the Russian-flagged Akademik Ioffe, designed and built in Finland as a scientific research vessel in 1989.Experts **on board** presented on topics including climate change, wildlife, Inuit culture and history, and early European explorers.

Comment: Good example, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: "They were aboard the vessel" simply states that they were present or inside the vessel without specifying their exact location within it. It implies that they were on the vessel but does not necessarily focus on their specific position.



On the other hand, "They were on board the vessel" emphasizes their presence and location specifically on the vessel. It highlights that they were not only present but also situated inside the vessel, suggesting a stronger connection to it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Ella! I've added your explanatory information into your answer, where it belongs. (Comments may be deleted at any time, but that information ought to stay with the answer.) However, please always cite the source of quoted text; otherwise your answer may run afoul of ELL's rules against plagiarism. (And if you wrote that example yourself, then you should say so.) Thanks!